# IBM MobileFirst: Worklight 6.2 database internal tables missing in Mobilefirst(6.3)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

The internal tables structure in worklight 6.2 in this link([Internal tables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/admin/r_internal_ibm_worklight_database_tables.html)) is missing for 6.3(MobileFirst).Where can we find it?

**Purpose :**
We would require that for a feature to create a SQL adapter over it to find out the number of registered devices for a user.

For example to display the user in his/her app showing the already registered devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest table reference for 6.3, here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.reference.doc/admin/r_internal_ibm_worklight_database_tables.html

The tables did not change in regards to the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @idan - Is it possible to build SQL adapter on these tables ? just wondering to cut down a lot of time.